# variable not binding value in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am passing variable, but it is not passing value.

I populates variable value here.

```
val Temp = sqlContext.read.parquet("Tabl1.parquet")
Temp.registerTempTable("temp")

val year = sqlContext.sql("""select value  from Temp where name="YEAR"""")
year.show()
```

here year.show() proper value.

I am passing the parameter here in below code.

```
val data = sqlContext.sql("""select count(*) from Table where Year='$year' limit 10""")
data.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question !

Answer (score 1):

The value `year` is a `Dataframe`, not a specific value (`Int` or `Long`). So when you use it inside a string interpolation, you get the result of `Dataframe.toString`, which isn't something you can use to compare values to (the toString returns a string representation of the Dataframe's schema).

If you can assume the `year` Dataframe has a *single* Row with a single *column* of type `Int`, and you want to get the value of that column - you get use `first().getAs[Int](0)` to get that value and then use it to construct your next query:

```
val year: DataFrame = sqlContext.sql("""select value from Temp where name="YEAR"""")
// get the first column of the first row:
val actualYear: Int = year.first().getAs[Int](0) 

val data = sqlContext.sql(s"select count(*) from Table where Year='$actualYear' limit 10")
```

If `value` column in `Temp` table has a different type (`String`, `Long`) - just replace the `Int` with that type.

Comment: I edited the code, but I am getting error "error: not found: type DataFrame"

Comment: Add the relevant import `import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` ?

Comment: It is imported, works fine. but now different error "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
"

Comment: As I wrote - that means column `value` in `Temp` table has type String - just change the `Int` to `String`: `val actualYear: String = year.first().getAs[String](0)`