# Variable substitution in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have two dataframes in scala both having data from two different tables but of same structure (`srcdataframe` and `tgttable`). I have to join these two based on composite primary key and select few columns and append two columns the code for which is as below:

```
for(i <- 2 until numCols) {
  srcdataframe.as("A")
    .join(tgttable.as("B"), $"A.INSTANCE_ID" === $"B.INSTANCE_ID" && 
       $"A.CONTRACT_LINE_ID" === $"B.CONTRACT_LINE_ID", "inner")
    .filter($"A." + srcColnm(i) =!= $"B." + srcColnm(i))
    .select($"A.INSTANCE_ID",
            $"A.CONTRACT_LINE_ID",
           "$"+"\""+"A."+srcColnm(i)+"\""+","+"$"+"\""+"B."+srcColnm(i)+"\"")
    .withColumn("MisMatchedCol",lit("\""+srcColnm(i)+"\""))
    .withColumn("LastRunDate",current_timestamp.cast("long"))
    .createOrReplaceTempView("IPF_1M_Mismatch"); 

hiveSQLContext.sql("Insert into table xxxx.f2f_Mismatch1 select t.* from (select * from IPF_1M_Mismatch) t");}
```

Here are the things am trying to do:

1. Inner join of `srcdataframe` and `tgttable` based on `instance_id` and `contract_line_id`.
2. Select only `instance_id`, `contract_line_id`, `mismatched_col_values`, hardcode of `mismatched_col_nm`, `timestamp`.
3. `srcColnm(i)` is an `array` of strings which contains the non-primary keys to be compared.

However, I am not able to resolve the variables inside the dataframe in the for loop. I tried looking up for solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277467/variable-not-binding-value-in-spark) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679463/scala-string-variable-substitution?rq=1). I got to know that it may be because of the way spark substitutes the variables only at compile time, in this case I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating columns with `$`, you can simply use strings or the `col()` function. I would also recommend performing the `join` outside of the for as it's an expensive operation. Slightly changed code, the main difference to solve your problem is in the select:

```
val df =  srcdataframe.as("A")
  .join(tgttable.as("B"), Seq("INSTANCE_ID", "CONTRACT_LINE_ID"), "inner")

for(columnName <- srcColnm) {
  df.filter(col("A." + columnName) =!= col("B." + columnName))
    .select("INSTANCE_ID", "CONTRACT_LINE_ID", "A." + columnName, "B." + columnName)
    .withColumn("MisMatchedCol", lit(columnName))
    .withColumn("LastRunDate", current_timestamp().cast("long"))
    .createOrReplaceTempView("IPF_1M_Mismatch")

  // Hive command
}
```

---

Regarding the problem in `select`:

`$` is short for the `col()` function, it's selecting a column in the dataframe by name. The problem in the `select` is that the two first arguments `col("A.INSTANCE_ID")` and `col("A.CONTRACT_LINE_ID") are two columns (`$`replaced by`col()` for clarity).

However, the next two arguments are strings. It is not possible to mix these two, either all arguments should be columns or all are strings. As you used `"A."+srcColnm(i)` to build up the column name `$` can't be used, however, you could have used `col("A."+srcColnm(i))`.

Comment: Thanks... it worked... please help me understand the problem that was there in select and what does '$' do

Comment: @Vinod Added more information to the answer about the problem in `select` and `$`. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification